# Python не находит модуль: ImportError: DLL load failed при импорте geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скрипт начинается с импорта
`import geopandas as gp`
И сразу выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rashid/PycharmProjects/untitled1/1.py", line 1, in <module>
import geopandas as gp
  File "C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from geopandas.io.file import read_file
  File "C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 3, in <module>
import fiona
  File "C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
  File "C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 9, in <module>
from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Хотя фиона вроде есть

Answer (score 1):

Нашел способ. Установил `pip install GDAL-2.2.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` и все "поехало".